# Error getting length of array stored in state

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to count the number of items in an array that's stored in my redux state. Here's my code:

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

const userCompanies = user.companyId;

if ( userCompanies.length == 1 ) {
    alert('Only one company');
};
```

My user object looks like this (and outputs fine via console log):

```
Object {
"companyId": Array [
    "NhOmasfaJWpFDd9erU",
],
"email": "example@gmail.com",
"userId": "jGibL0twsafsqYAmxx9X0C2",
}
```

However, I get *Cannot read property 'length' of undefined* when loading the screen. Am I trying to run the count too early or something? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is a whole container for those information ( companyId, email..)

To access that container, you need to do like this:

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
```

The first `.user` is the key you defined in the `App.js`. The second is the state container in redux

Then when access `companyId`, you just need to:

```
user.companyId
```